# Django : form is not saved into my database

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-1.8

Altough my form to send an offer is correctly displayed and I have no error when submitting the offers, they are not saved in my database.
I know that by checking the admin site, no objects are saved.
But on the other hand, I already have written the code for the registration and users are saved in the database.

I suspect the ForeignKey relation between my 2 models as the culprit.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):

username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=False)
password1 = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
password2 = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
mail = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=False)
birthday = models.DateField(blank=False)
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, verbose_name="Date d'inscription")
def __str__(self):
    return self.username 

class Offer(models.Model):

publisher = models.ForeignKey(User)
content = models.TextField()
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False,    verbose_name="Date de parution")

def __str__(self):
    return self.publisher.username
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password, check_password
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from myuser.models import User, Offer

class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        widgets = {
        'password1' : forms.PasswordInput(),
        'password2' : forms.PasswordInput(),
        }
        fields = ("username", "password1", "password2", "mail")

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("les mots de passes ne correspondent pas")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.password1 = make_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        user.password2 = make_password(self.cleaned_data["password2"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label="nom d'utilisateur")
    password = forms.CharField(label="mot de passe",
                                widget = forms.PasswordInput)
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(LoginForm, self).clean()
        username = cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        if check_password(password, user.password1):
            return cleaned_data
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Le nom d'utilisateur et le mot de passe ne correspondent pas")

class SendOfferForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Offer
        fields = ('content',)
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

from myuser.models import User, Offer
from myuser.forms import UserCreationForm, LoginForm, SendOfferForm

def get_logged_user_from_request(request):
    if 'logged_user_id' in request.session:
        logged_user_id = request.session['logged_user_id']
        return User.objects.get(id=logged_user_id)
    else:
        return None

def register(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request,
           'myuser/create_account.html',
           {'user_form': user_form, 'registered': registered} )

def login(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        try:
            if form.is_valid():
               user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST.get('username')) 
               logged_user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST.get('username'))
               request.session['logged_user_id'] = logged_user.id
               return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                error = "le nom d'utilisateur et le mot de passe ne correspondent pas"
                return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")
    else:
        form = LoginForm
    return render(request, 'myuser/mylogin.html', locals())



def send_offer(request):
    sent = False
    logged_user = get_logged_user_from_request(request)
    if logged_user:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            try:
                offerform = SendOfferForm(request.POST, instance=logged_user)
                if offerform.is_valid():        
                    sent = True
                    offerform.save()
                else:
                    print(offerform.errors)
            except:
                return HttpResponse("drapeau except")
        else:
            offerform = SendOfferForm(instance=logged_user)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Vous n'êtes pas connecté")
    return render(request, 'myuser/send_offer.html', locals())
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('myuser.views',
    url(r'^inscription/$', 'register',  name='create_account'),
    url(r'^connexion/$', 'login', name='login'),
    url(r'^envoyer_une_offre$', 'send_offer', name='send_offer'),
    )
```

send_offer.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<h1> Offer </h1>

{% if not sent %}
<p> write your offer <p/>

    <form action="{% url "send_offer" %}" method='POST' class='sendofferform'>
        {{ form.errors }}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ offerform.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
{% else %}
Offer is published
<a href="/poster_une_offre">publish another offer?</a><br /> 
<a href="/">get back to the homepage</a><br />
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myuser.models import User, Offer#, Message

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'username', 'status', 'college', 'apercu_description')
    list_filter = ('id', 'username', 'birthday')
    date_hierarchy = 'date'
    ordering = ('date', )
    search_fields = ('username', 'description')

    def apercu_description(self, User):

        text = User.description[0:40]
        if len(User.description) > 40:
            return '%s' % text
        else:
            return text

class OfferAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'publisher', 'apercu_offre')
    list_filter = ('id', )
    date_hierarchy = 'date'
    ordering = ('date', )
    search_fields = ('publisher',)

    def apercu_offre(self, Offer):        
        text = Offer.content[0:40]
        if len(Offer.content) > 40:
            return '%s' % text
        else:
            return text

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(Offer, OfferAdmin)
```

All of the other function works (register and login) and the register() function correctly saves the user but the send_offer() function, which is very similar to the register function doesn't work and after searching on internet for hours, I still have no idea why the offers are not saved.

But when I try to add an offer in the admin site, it seems to work.

Besides, I tried to save an offer in the python manage.py shell :

```
>>> Offer.publisher = "a"
>>> Offer.content = "lalalala"
>>> Offer.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 69, in handle
    self.run_shell(shell=options['interface'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 61, in run_shell
    raise ImportError
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

EDIT : The solution was to add these lines :

```
    if offerform.is_valid():        
        sent = True
        offer = offerform.save(commit=False)
        offer.publisher = User.objects.get(id=logged_user.id)
        offer.save()
```

Please, note that logged_user is a function, which is described in view.py.

Comment: Don't know if this solves your problem but you forgot the closing `</form>` tag in your template.

Comment: Unfortunately not. But it was a mistake indeed.

Comment: just to be sure - can you put a print right above the "offerform.save()" and make sure its called?

Comment: I just added "print("OK")" just above the offerform.save(). When I submit an offer I can't see OK but I'm not sure it would have work anyway.

I also have my parameter "sent =  True" when an offer is submitted.

Comment: Try importing ipd and put ipdb.set_trace() after the save. Then in the debugger console check the values of all the variables involved and step through the code to see what's going on

Comment: Additionally. I don't see a line where you set the publisher to an existing user. Since you are not including this field in the form you have to set it manually before saving.

Comment: When you instantiate the offer form on post it needs a Offer instance not a logged in user.

Comment: @Vincent Maréchal  why wouldn't it work anyway? looks like your form is not really valid so it doesn't save.

Comment: I'm not really well familiarized with django and I didn't expect print() would work. I'll try it on a working function to see the outcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a ModelForm if you don't pass any object when its instantiated It will create a new object in the database of the specified type. So in this case on your SendOfferForm you have specified Offer. IF you do pass an existing object it has to be the specified type in this case Offer.

It looks like you are trying to automatically fill the publisher field with the currently logged in user. In order to do this you need to manually set the publisher field to an instance of User.

If you intend for the form to create a new Offer in the database do this

```
offerform = SendOfferForm(request.POST)
```

If you are trying to update a current offer THEN you would need to pass an instance object into the form

```
offerform = SendOfferForm(request.POST, instance=someOffer)
```

To manually add the user field call save on your form with commit=False this will return an offer object WITHOUT saving to the DB. At this point you have a chance to customize the data in object and then save.

```
offer = offerform.save(commit=False)
offer.publisher = request.user.id
offer.save()
```

All of this is explained in more detail in the django documentation
[ModelForm documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
Do you mean I should write  something like that in views.py:

Offer_publisher = logged_in_user.username
offerform = SendOfferForm(request.POST, instance=Offer_publisher)

instead of :

offerform = SendOfferForm(request.POST, instance=logged_user)?

Comment: Yes a modelform needs an instance of an object it represents. You have to set the fk feild manually if your not allowing that feild to be edited by the user on the form.

Comment: no it's worse.  
I've got the error :  
  
AttributeError at /envoyer_une_offre  
'str' object has no attribute '_meta'  

I just put publisher = logged_user.username in the beginning of my function and then I wrote offerform = SendOfferForm(request.POST, instance=publisher)

Comment: You need to have a read of the docs. Why are you setting a OfferForm with an instance other then Offer ? Additionally when you set the publisher it needs the instance not the username. I'm mobile now so it's hard to write any code snippet to show you. When I'm home later If its not resolved I'll show you some code.

Comment: I thought that hidden fields such as Offer.id and offer.publisher would be filled with the fields of the User model as they are already filled with the data of the logged_in_user. I would be grateful if you could show me the code snippet that could resolve my problem. It's very strange but I can't find any examples of saving a such model in my books.

Comment: we almost succeded. I've got the error ValueError at /envoyer_une_offre

Cannot assign "1": "Offer.publisher" must be a "User" instance. I'll fix that tomorrow. Now, I think i'm able to find the solution. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Pass it a user object not the ID. My mistake man. Otherwise it should work for you.

Comment: It's fixed, I wrote the solution for people who might have the same problem in my edit. Thank you :)